# objective-c: How to access textfield in first row of second section of Tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have a Tableview I want to change the value of textField on the first row of second section?

I assign it tag value which lets say is 2.

Now how to access that TextField with tag.

Comment: Can you Please provide some code what you have done.

Comment: Can you Please provide some code what you have done.

Comment: where you want to access this text field

Comment: I want to change its value on viewDidLoad ... actually this value come from NSNotification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a tag to that text field and by using that tag you can change the value.

```
UITextField *tempField = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag: tag]; 

tempField.text = @"Your data";
```

Comment: the tag value of that field is 2 .. now how to access it.

Comment: UITextField *tempField = (UITextField *) [self.view viewWithTag: tag]; tempField.text = @"Your data";

Comment: Be extra cautious while using this. Because if you want to get a text field with tag 0 !!! then you may get any view which has tag as zero (by default all labels in your xib may have tag 0 !!) may not be a text field in particular.

Answer (score 0):

If you wnat to access your textField inside some table view methods  so you can do this:-

```
UITextField *tView=(UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
```

If you have to access your textField outside some tableVIew method than you have to do :-

`lastSelectedPath=indexPath;`do where you have added your text field.You will need its indexPath.Make it a global variable.

```
UITableViewCell *prevoiusCell=(UITableViewCell *)[*yourtabelviewname* cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastSelectedPath];
UITextField *tView=(UITextField *)[prevoiusCell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
```